# Heroku vue-loader build failure

Tags: html, heroku, vue.js

When I try to deploy my Vue application to Heroku I get the following build error that I was not receiving before:

```
ERROR in ./~/vue-loader/lib/template-compiler?{"id":"data-v-10bd33eb","hasScoped":false,"transformToRequire":{"video":"src","source":"src","img":"src","image":"xlink:href"},"buble":{"transforms":{}}}!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=template&index=0!./src/components/About.vue
       Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../assets/Noam.jpg' in '/tmp/build_4e0206e4d9f7ce1235a91f8c7dbd5035/src/components'
        @ ./~/vue-loader/lib/template-compiler?{"id":"data-v-10bd33eb","hasScoped":false,"transformToRequire":{"video":"src","source":"src","img":"src","image":"xlink:href"},"buble":{"transforms":{}}}!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=template&index=0!./src/components/About.vue 2:1080-1109
        @ ./src/components/About.vue
        @ ./src/router/index.js
        @ ./src/main.js

         Build failed with errors.

       npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
       npm ERR! errno 1
       npm ERR! sharefare@1.0.0 build: `node build/build.js`
```

The error is only complaining about a single image (`Noam.jpg`) that has the same dimensions and properties as the others. The file is located in the `assets` folder that is in the same directory as the `components`. When I start the server and go on the site, the image loads but the failure only occurs on the Heroku build.

**About.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="about">
    <br>
    <div id="header">
      <h1>Who we are</h1>
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li><figure><img src="../assets/Paul.jpg"><figcaption>Paul Attara</figcaption></figure></li>
      <li><figure><img src="../assets/Lucas.jpg"><figcaption>Lucas Bellido</figcaption></figure></li>
      <li><figure><img src="../assets/Arielle.jpg"><figcaption>Arielle Lasry</figcaption></figure></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li><figure><img src="../assets/Kamy.jpg"><figcaption>Kamy Moussavi</figcaption></figure></li>
      <li><figure><img src="../assets/Eden.jpg"><figcaption>Eden Ovadia</figcaption></figure></li>
      <li><figure><img src="../assets/Noam.jpg"><figcaption>Noam Suissa</figcaption></figure></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <router-link to="/" id="back">Back to Home</router-link>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: When this happens to me, I always check github to make sure I actually checked the file in...

Comment: @JimB. It is there with a capital JPG extension

Comment: Let me guess, you develop on a mac?

Comment: @JimB. Yes lol. Amazing! It worked. Thank you!

Comment: I've been burned by that one 100 times.

Comment: Vue-loader is in your devdependencies? as i know heroku won't install dev dependencies by default. it handles by `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION` environment variable. Try to set to `false`.